# NServiceBus 6 (6.0.0-beta0004) - The requested service 'NServiceBus.RecoverabilityExecutorFactory' has not been registered

Tags: nservicebus

Just running with a vanilla **NServiceBus 6.0.0-beta0004**

```
var endpointConfiguration = new EndpointConfiguration("endpoint");
endpointInstance = await Endpoint.Start(endpointConfiguration).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

This throws an exception:

```
Bus.ProgramService An unhandled error has occurred.
Autofac.Core.Registration.ComponentNotRegisteredException: The requested service 'NServiceBus.RecoverabilityExecutorFactory' has not been registered. To avoid this exception, either register a component to provide the service, check for service registration using IsRegistered(), or use the ResolveOptional() method to resolve an optional dependency.
   at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.ResolveService(IComponentContext context, Service service, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.Resolve(IComponentContext context, Type serviceType)
   at NServiceBus.AutofacObjectBuilder.Build(Type typeToBuild) in D:\Code\GitHub\agupta-au\NServiceBus\src\NServiceBus.Core\ObjectBuilder\Autofac\AutofacObjectBuilder.cs:line 39
   at NServiceBus.CommonObjectBuilder.Build[T]() in D:\Code\GitHub\agupta-au\NServiceBus\src\NServiceBus.Core\ObjectBuilder\Common\CommonObjectBuilder.cs:line 28
   at NServiceBus.StartableEndpoint.CreateReceivers() in D:\Code\GitHub\agupta-au\NServiceBus\src\NServiceBus.Core\StartableEndpoint.cs:line 93
   at NServiceBus.StartableEndpoint.<Start>d__1.MoveNext() in D:\Code\GitHub\agupta-au\NServiceBus\src\NServiceBus.Core\StartableEndpoint.cs:line 45
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at NServiceBus.Endpoint.<Start>d__1.MoveNext() in D:\Code\GitHub\agupta-au\NServiceBus\src\NServiceBus.Core\Endpoint.cs:line 28
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
```

What am I missing? My understanding is that the Recoverability stuff is to do with the First Level Retries + Second Level Retries but I've not set this up yet.  Moreover, there seems to be discussion between the guys about this already: https://github.com/Particular/NServiceBus/pull/3828

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Can you share your configuration code please?

Comment: NServiceBus Beta 004 should not contain the RecoverabilityExecutorFactory. I just checked again, by downloading the nuget package from nuget.org and decompiling it. Can you elaborate how and where you get this version?

Comment: Ahh, I built using the GitHub repo for the rel 6.0.0.0 branch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Daniel already mentioned in the comments, this code should not be part of the available beta packages. It's highly recommended to stick with the available beta packages on NuGet instead because it's very likely to run into issues when using any persistence/transport package otherwise. The release-6.0.0 branch is still under active development.

(But of course that exception should not occur at all ;) )

Comment: Thanks, I am now using the nuget. On a side note, I've noticed a bug if I'm using Costura.Fody when using beta4. This seems to be a result of the change in mechanism on how assembly scanning is now based on an exclusion list rather than an inclusion list

Comment: @agAus you may want to report your issue on the official google groups over here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/particularsoftware

Comment: Just for completeness sake: I've switched to using NUnit for testing and I'm no longer seeing the issue. Just waiting for the product to come out of beta :)